# C - Linked List Insertion

Tags: c, linked-list

I've wanted to create 5 nodels and insert a new nodle between 3rd and 4th one. Here is the code.. When I run it, I do not get either error or output. What have I done wrong ? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{

                int data;
                struct node *next;

}node;


int main(void) {

                struct node *root, *newElement, *temp;

                // first node is created.
                root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                root->data = 11;

                // to create 4 nodes more after the first one is created.
                int i;
                for (i=0; i <= 3; i++){

                               root->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                               root = root->next;
                               root->data = (i * 10);

                }

                // new node to insert.
                newElement = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                newElement-> data = 1;



                temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

                temp = root->next->next;

                root->next -> next = newElement;

                newElement->next = temp;


                // print the values 
                int j;
                for(j=0; j<=4; j++){
                    root = root->next;
                    printf("%d\n", root->data);
                }


                return 0;

}
```

Comment: your cord insert to  between 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: 1) It will not be able to insert operation again. and You can not release the list. 2) Can not be detected in the last element. 3) It causes a memory leak.

Comment: The way to indicate that your question has been answered is to accept an answer. Please don't insert the answer into the question, and please don't add the word "SOLVED" to the title. If none of the existing answers solved your problem, feel free to post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying `root` when you are creating the nodes, you should create some kind of iterator that starts at root and gets modified instead so that you don't lose the initial position.

Try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;


int main(void) {
    struct node *root, *newElement, *temp, *iterator;

    // first node is created.
    root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    iterator = root;
    iterator->data = 11;

    // to create 4 nodes more after the first one is created.
    int i;
    for (i=0; i <= 3; i++){
       iterator->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
       iterator = iterator->next;
       iterator->data = (i * 10);
    }

    // new node to insert.
    newElement = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newElement-> data = 1;

    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    iterator = root;
    temp = iterator->next->next;

    iterator->next->next = newElement;

    newElement->next = temp;

    iterator = root;
    // print the values 
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<=4; j++){
        printf("%d\n", root->data);
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
root = temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));//no need cast from void*
temp->data = 11;

int i;
for (i=0; i <= 3; i++){
    //don't change root
    temp->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp = temp->next;
    temp->data = (i * 10);
}
temp->next = NULL;//next of last node need set to NULL 

newElement = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
newElement-> data = 1;

//temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));//no need (this make memory leak)
temp = root->next->next;
root->next->next = newElement;
newElement->next = temp;


for(temp = root; temp; temp = temp->next){
    printf("%d\n", temp->data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create the 4 new nodes, you reassign your `root` pointer downstream in the list and loose access to the upstream elements.  Intead, set `temp = root` before the loop, then use `temp` inside the loop instead.

```
            temp = root;
            int i;
            for (i=0; i <= 3; i++){
                           temp->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                           temp = temp->next;
                           temp->data = (i * 10);
                           temp->next = NULL;
            }
```